# Javascript code isn't getting into my document ready listener. (forge iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, trigger.io, forge

This is my entire javascript file for the home page of my app. Any ideas as to why it never gets into the document ready listener?

```
var photos;
forge.request.ajax({
  url: "http://photos-url.com/pics.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    photos = data;
  },
  error: function(error) {
    forge.logging.info("Couldn't fetch pics!");
  }
});

//logging output works here

$(function() {
  //logging output doesn't work here
  //I'm trying to append to the html here, but it never gets into this code
});
```

Comment: I've never seen anyone do this with JQuery.  Are you putting a function where a string should be on accident, or is this a functionality of JQuery I've never seen?

Comment: Can you put a little bit more of your code?, because is dificult to see the problem if nobody knows what forge is and when you fire the ajax request

Comment: Do you have a syntax error in your ready handler? If logging is working elsewhere, that's my first guess... I'd recommend taking everything out of your JS and adding it back in to see at what point it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain requests are prohibited for security reasons (same as in desktop browsers). You must configure environment to allow requests to your domain. Look at https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/request.html for details.

Comment: Thanks! This request is actually working just fine, but that's good to know for the future!

Answer (score 0):

json files are usually allowed to be read from cross domain and even if this one would't be, I still doubt it could affect ready event. I'm not using document ready function on my page as I was having simillar issues (it fires few minutes after page is loaded, or doesn't fire at all). You could try window.onload or document.onload events. I'd also try to find out how document.readyState behaves and eventually check it manually with interval or try to bind event listener to it.